# How to keep 6 months of history in git but make 3 months of data visible

Tags: git, github

We have a git repository that contains some files and one folder, called download. The download folder has several sub-folders and gets updated with one new folder every month. I would like to keep 6 months of history for the download folder in git, but like show only 3 months of data. I am thinking of following steps. Please advise.

$ find download/* -maxdepth 0 -type d -mtime +180 -exec git filter-branch --force --tree-filter 'git rm -rf --ignore-unmatch {}' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all \;

$ for ref in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/original); do git update-ref -d $ref; done

$ find download/* -maxdepth 0 -type d -mtime +90 -exec git rm {} \;

$ git push origin --force --all

$ git push origin --force --tags

Comment: Can you explain what your downloads folder is for?

At the moment all I can tell you is Git/Github and source control like SVN does not work that way. Source control systems can't hide something that is in the record, it will always be there (technically even deleting the file the history and the file are still there).

Comment: if you have commits for each month why dont change to the version what you whant, for example git status, see your last commit and make git checkout sha-of-commit, where sha-of-commit its a specefic commit of 3 months ago, but how i wrote @walt Sorensen the history of your project still here at least you delete this commits

Comment: @walt Sorensen The download folder is in Repo which contains other sub-folders.  For example, download/1501, download/1502, download/1503, and etc. Every month the download folder gets a  new data which end-up in its own sub-directory (e.g. 1501, 1502, ...). The goal is to shrink Git Repo size by keeping only 6 months of history and remove (git rm) any  folder and files that are older than 3 months. For example, GIt history is tracking sub-folders 1501...1506 under download folder but users can only see sub-folders 1504...1506 (3 months worth of data) when they do download folder listing.

Comment: your process for 6 moths of history should work just fine, and complies with how source control works. 

There is just no method to hide active items in your repository. 
Nor is there a method to remove selected files from the source download.